# Flag and upvote buttons for comments are now always visible

Tags: bug, comments, design

As far as I can recall flag and upvote buttons for comments were visible only on mouse over comment. Now I see them always:

> [image: comments]

At the same time "delete comment" button appears only on mouse move. Seems there is some inconsistency.

Comment: +1 for the specific point about the delete button, which I don't believe has been mentioned yet. (I'm of two minds about that change.)